# Less smoothed line in ggplot2, alternatives to geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

Using the following data:

```
> str(attribute)
'data.frame':   431 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ pos: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ att: num  0.652 0.733 0.815 1.079 0.885 ...   *[between 0 and 3]
```

and:

```
ggplot(attribute, aes(x=pos, y=att)) + geom_line() + geom_smooth()
```

I did: 
[image]

I would like to progressively smooth the black curve, not "as much as" geom_smooth default did. I've tried `n`, `level` options, but didn't do what I want. Which would be the best way to increase smoothing progressively? (e.g. average 2 values in one, then try 3 in one, and so on). I guess it's something really easy or achievable without using `geom_smooth`, but I don't know what to search/look for. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is documented in `stat_smooth`. The default smoother is `loess`, and additional arguments are passed on to it, as specified for the description of the `...` argument. So what you want is `span`:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x = wt,y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(span = 0.4)
```

Additionally, `loess` accepts a `degree` argument for more control over the amount of smoothing.

Comment: `degree` looks deprecated but span helpful